# I have a 32 bit app on the google play store. What happens after August 1, 2019

Tags: android, 32bit-64bit

I am getting ready to update my 32 bit Android app, but not before August 1. Can I wait until some other time (August 15th say) to update the app, and users can still download my up until I update? Or must I update to 64 bit by 1 August.

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, only new uplodads and updates to existing apps are restricted. so it will not be removed, but you will not be able to update it until it supports 64b

Comment: no, i believe this is for most apps, not sure exactly what the "native" part referrs to, but i know there is an exception for Unity so that might be it. i have been getting warnings about this on my xamarin uploads to store so atleast those are affected. by august 1st 2021 they will remove all apps that does not support 64 bit

Comment: It seems that only apps with "native libraries" are involved https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html